# rspec test fails because of "unexpected arguments" while explicitly using ArgumentMatcher "anything()"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

While using RSpec (2.10.0), machinist (2.0), rspec-rails (2.10.1) and rails (2.3.6) I am having issues using the RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatcher `anything`:

I have two `it` blocks using the matcher, while the first succeeds but the second raises the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Post.make!(:community => @community)
<Notification::Delayed (class)> received :create with unexpected arguments
expected: (#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::AnyArgMatcher:0x00000104eff8f8>, #<User ...> , "event", "interval")
got: (#<Post>, <User...>, "event", "interval")
```

These are the it-blocks (i already changed their order, their precedence, started them independently and each in a single test run), but still no.1 passes and no.2 fails:

```
it "should create a delayed notification per default" do
  Notification::Email.should_not_receive(:notification)
  Notification::Delayed.should_receive(:create).with(anything, user, "event", "interval")
  Post.make!(:community => @community)
end

it "should create a delayed notification on user request" do
  NotificationSetting.make! :user => user, :event => 'event', :role => 'community,moderators', :interval => 'interval'
  Notification::Email.should_not_receive(:notification)
  Notification::Delayed.should_receive(:create).with(anything, user, 'event', 'interval')
  Post.make!(:community => @community)
end
```

For simplicity reasons I omitted why using this anything()-method: its because the Object handed in as first argument can be a Post or of a subclass of Post. Because of that in mind i went through all other ArgumentMatchers (:duck_type, :kind_of? ...) with no luck.

I am totally stuck, how could that happen, that this Error even occurs? Doesn't the [doc in its "Argument Matchers' section](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames) say, that "argument can be anything at all" - so how can there be such an error?
And the next thing that creeps me, is my shiftlessness about the appearance of the error in the second context not in the first. Shouldn't it fail on both at least?

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain it, but there seemed to be something wrong with my spec_helper.
It is impossible to reproduce the error in a different project.

Sorry, for bothering you.
I will post an answer when I finally found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test with :

```
Notification::Delayed.should_receive(:create).with(kind_of(Post), user, 'event', 'interval')
```

The subclasses of Post are kind of Post too.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion, but unfortunately the expectations are still not met :(